# JavaFX How can I get the coordinates of an object in 3D scene

Tags: java, javafx, 3d

For example - there is such a code

```
    //create new cylinder
    Cylinder cylinder = new Cylinder(2, 6);
    ...
    //somewhere add transform
    cylinder.getTransforms().add(new Translate(0, -5, 0));
    ...
    //and somewhere i call
    cylinder.setTranslateX(3);
    cylinder.setTranslateY(-2);
```

as a result, the cylinder moves and its coordinates on the scene {3, -7, 0}

for get actual coords i try something like that:

```
    double coordY = 0;

    for(Transform t : cylinder.getTransforms() ){
        coordY += t.getTy();
    }

    coordY += cylinder.getTranslateY();
```

it work, but this is clearly not the most rational way...
**UPDATE 1**

As rightly remarked [fabian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2991525/fabian)

The method does not take into account if a rotation was made relative to a point other than the origin

for examle:

```
        Rotate rotate = new Rotate();
        rotate.setAngle(60);

        rotate.setPivotX(2);
        rotate.setPivotY(1);
        rotate.setPivotZ(3);

        cylinder.getTransforms().add(rotate);
```

in this case, the result will be incorrect

How can I get the real coordinates{x,y,z} of this cylinder or any other object like Shape3d or MeshView

Thanks!

Comment: This only works for translations. Add e.g. a rotation around the origin any in could calcualtion the result does not change. Assumin a rotation of 180° with an axis ortogonal to the vector from the origin to the point the vector would be mirrored, i.e. `yNew = -yOld`... Also there's [`localToParent`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#localToParent(double,double,double)) allowing you to convert a specific point in the coordinate system of the cylinder to the coordiantes of the containing `Group`(?).

Comment: Yes, you’re right, my example doesn’t take into account the rotation and the result will be wrong, unless the rotation is made around the local origin. Thanks for the remark!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query the [`Node#getBoundsInParent`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#boundsInParentProperty) property:

> The rectangular bounds of this Node which include its transforms. `boundsInParent` is calculated by taking the local bounds (defined by `boundsInLocal`) and applying the transform created by setting the following additional variables
>
> 1. `transforms` ObservableList
> 2. `scaleX`, `scaleY`, `scaleZ`
> 3. `rotate`
> 4. `layoutX`, `layoutY`
> 5. `translateX`, `translateY`, `translateZ`
>
> The resulting bounds will be conceptually in the coordinate space of the `Node`'s parent, however the node need not have a parent to calculate these bounds.
>
> Note that this method does not take the node's visibility into account; the computation is based on the geometry of this `Node` only.
>
> This property will always have a non-null value.
>
> Note that `boundsInParent` is automatically recomputed whenever the geometry of a node changes, or when any of the following the change: transforms `ObservableList`, any of the translate, layout or scale variables, or the rotate variable. For this reason, it is an error to bind any of these values in a node to an expression that depends upon this variable. For example, the x or y variables of a shape, or `translateX`, `translateY` should never be bound to `boundsInParent` for the purpose of positioning the node.

You'll get a [`Bounds`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/geometry/Bounds.html) object which has methods for querying the location and dimensions of the node, including for three dimensional objects. As stated in the above documentation, the *bounds-in-parent* takes into account the applied transformations (it's the *bounds-in-local* + transformations). Of course, the values are all within the context of the node's parent. If you need the coordinates in a different space then you need to convert them—the `Node` class provides many methods for this purpose.

Comment: Hello, Slaw! Thanks for the answer! If I understood everything correctly, then in my case the solution will look something like this: `Bounds bounds = cylinder.getBoundsInParent(); double coordY = bounds.getMinY() + bounds.getHeight()*0.5`

Comment: If you're looking to get the center `y` coordinate (relative to the parent), yes. Note you can use [`Bounds#getCenterY()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/geometry/Bounds.html#getCenterY()) in JavaFX 11+.